# How to receive the message text and ID from an Azure Service Bus Queue in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I just created in Azure an ServiceBus Queue and I would like to get the text context of the Queue.

But evertime I want to read the values I did not get nothing back.

Maybe you can explain me who I can do this in the right way. Which trigger should I use? the Queue trigger or the service bus queue trigger. I'm a little bit confused.

[image: an example of my LogicApp]

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Have you tried the "When a message is received in a queue (auto-complete)" trigger? That always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and i got expected results and i followed below process:

[image]

Then in compose :

```
id = message id(from dynamic content) and Message = base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])
```

[image]

Then in service bus:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Please try to follow this you will get messages as I got.